# Hice un commit cuando estaba en un commit antiguo, cómo puedo encontrar ese commit?

Tags: git, github

Estaba trabajando en algunos cambios cuando hice un commit mientras estaba en un commit anterior, ejecuté el comando `history` y encontré lo siguiente.

```
1000  git checkout 7227... <-- Estaba en la rama main y luego hice un checkout al commit 7227...
  --- Trabajando en cambios ---
1012  git commit -am "Login corrections" <-- No había notado que no estaba trabajando en la rama main
1013  git pull origin main <-- Noté el problema y luego me cambié a la rama main
```

Finalmente hice un checkout a la rama `main` y ahora no encuentro el commit que hice con el mensaje *Login corrections* como mostré anteriormente. Intenté encontrarlo con `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` pero no hallé algo parcido.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, Hector. Solo preguntas en español, en todo caso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo que puedes hacer es:

```
git cherry-pick HEAD@{1} # traer los cambios de la revision en la que estaba antes
```

Eso, si luego de hacer el checkout no haz hecho absolutamente mas nada.

Si lo que deseas es solo ver esa revision, puedes hacer:

```
git log HEAD@{1}
```

o simplemente crea una rama para que puedas tenerlo a mano:

```
git branch blah HEAD@{1}
```

De cualquier forma, siempre te puedes apoyar en el reflog

```
git reflog
```